# running local server .py prompts a text editor instead of opening page

Tags: php, python, lamp

I have a file which currently works on my production site as mysite.com/pages/lister.py.

I am trying to build a local version of the site. The index.php works and other pages work, but when I go to a .py page like: localhost/pages/lister.py it doesnt change the site, it just asks if I want to use gedit to open the file.

My guess is that my local config is off somewhere, but I do not know where to start when approaching this problem.

NOTES:

I am running  a lamp server which I downloaded using `sudo apt-get install lamp-server^`

and my apache config is `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf` and contains:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/
    <Directory /var/www/>
        Options ExecCGI Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
        AddHandler cgi-script .py
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

**EDIT 1**

This may be the solution to my question but its not really working yet so idk yet.

I ran

```
sudo a2enmod cgi
sudo service apache2 restart
```

and now it gives:

Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at webmaster@localhost to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80

Comment: I'm pretty new to full stack development, but it's helpful to me to get involved in these discussions! I'll ask a few obvious things first: Is the .py file placed in a directory that your web server sees? Does the .py file actually write some HTML? Is your server configuration setup to handle .py files?

Comment: the file is in the right place and does write html, I added my config above. @PatJones

Comment: Well the internal server error is kind of a good sign...it means that it is trying to load the page. In my configuration settings I don't have "Multiviews" under Options...not sure what that does. I also have `AllowOverride All`, and `Require all granted`, but not sure that they are appropriate in your case.

Answer (score 0):

My configuration for .pl and .py scripts that write HTML directly out to a page is the following:

```
<Directory "[put production path here]">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

As I'm new to full stack work, I'm not sure if this is appropriate for your situation, but it might be worth a try.